# C++ Linked List---how to insert every new data into tail?

Tags: c++, header, linked-list

I need help with these codes that will ask for 3 input integers(AddToFront function) and then display them in last-to-first order, ex;  input 1=1 input 2=2 input 3=3 and then these will be displayed as 3 2 1...

I've been trying to reverse it to first-to-last order with the AddToLast function..I understand how the linked list works,i think,but i am having problems turning it to codes..Also if someone could please explain to me how to set the pTail as the last node, that would be helpfull..

Thanks in advance to anyone that could help..

```
//List.h
//Declaration of class List

#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

template <class DataType>
class List
{
private:
    class Node
    {
    public:
        DataType data;
        Node *link;
    };

    Node *pHead;
    Node *pCurr;
    Node *pTail;
    int numItem;

public:
    List();
    ~List();
    void AddToFront();
    void AddToLast();
    bool Traverse(DataType, int&);
    void printData();
    int NoOfItem();
};
#endif

//Define the implementation of all methods in class List

template <class DataType>
List<DataType>::List(){
    numItem=0;
    pHead=0;
    pTail; //knp x boleh????
}

template <class DataType>
List<DataType>::~List(){}

//template <class DataType>
//void List<DataType>::AddToFront()
//{
//  DataType item;
//  Node *pNew = new Node;
//  cout<<"Enter data: ";
//  cin>>item;
//  pNew->data=item;    //put item in node pnew
//  pNew->link=pHead;   //use pHead link for pNew
//  pHead=pNew;         //make pNew as pHead
//  numItem++;
//}

template <class DataType>
void List<DataType>::AddToLast()
{
    DataType item;
    Node *pNew = new Node;
    cout<<"Enter data: ";
    cin>>item;
    pNew->data=item;
    pNew->link=pHead;
    pHead=pNew;

    pNew->NUll;

    numItem++;
}

template <class DataType>
void List<DataType>::printData()
{
    pCurr=pTail;
    while (pCurr!=0)
    {
        cout<<pCurr->data<<" ";
        pCurr=pCurr->link;
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}

template <class DataType>
int List<DataType>::NoOfItem()
{   return numItem; }

template <class DataType>
bool List<DataType>::Traverse(DataType target,int& loc)
{
    if (numItem==0)
        cout<<"There is no item in the list."<<endl;
    else
    {
        pCurr=pHead;
        loc=0;
        while (pCurr->data !=target && pCurr->link !=0)
        {
            pCurr=pCurr->link;
            loc++;
        }

        if (pCurr->data==target)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

---

```
//ListMain.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "List.h"
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int target, loc;
    List<int> x;

    for (int i=1;i<4;i++)
    {
        x.AddToLast();
    }

    cout<<"\nMumber of item Now : "<<x.NoOfItem();
    cout<<"\nThe List are : "<<endl;
    x.printData();

    cout<<"\nEnter the search item : ";
    cin>>target;

    if (x.Traverse(target,loc)==true)
    {
       cout<<"Item is found at location : "
       <<loc<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Item is not found. \n";
    }
}
```

Comment: You should understand that software development is not just writing code.  In fact, if you get the data right, the code often almost writes itself. There is another development phase called 'debugging'.  This is often REALLY HARD, and inexperienced developers often try dumping code here in an attempt to get an SO contributor to do the ditch-digging of getting stuff working.  We don't like doing manual work, so you should find out how to do such tasks yourself and only post here when you are really stuck, with details of what you have found out so far.

Comment: Let's not forget the other phase between writing code and debugging: writing tests. E.g. you should write a test that appends "3" to an empty list, and check that the list is then one long and contains just the element 3.

Answer (score 0):

Traverse() looks ok to me, although its algorithm is somewhat convoluted. Also, there's no need to use a class member, just for the benefit of that method. This is what locally-scoped variables are for.

All that code, the entire function, can simply be replaced by

```
template <class DataType>
bool List<DataType>::Traverse(DataType target,int& loc)
{
    Node *p;

    for (p=pHead; p; p=p->link)
        if (p->data == target)
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

That certainly looks much simpler, compared to all of what you have, so far.

As far as setting `pTail`, I think you can figure it out yourself after considering the following facts:

1. Initially, in the constructor, the list is empty, so `pTail` would naturally be null.
2. You're always adding to the head, therefore, the very first node added to the list will be its permanent tail node.
3. After you set `pTail` it will no longer be null.
4. Therefore, when adding a new node to the head, if `pTail` is null, this must be the new permanent tail node.